# preg_replace problem

Tags: preg-replace, helper

I have `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` echoed, the problem is when it is echoed from xampp it shows, like this:

```
C:/xampp/hdocs
```

and when echoed from PHPed it shows

```
C:\\xampp\\htdocs.
```

I want to replace `"C:\\xampp\\htdocs"` with `"C:/xampp/hdocs"` but I'm not able to do so using `preg_replace`.

Kindly help me !

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex for that. Use the `str_replace()` fnction:

```
str_replace('\\', '/', $str);
```